# MS Excel Drop Down for Viewing Different Data on Plot

Tags: excel

I have several plots that I would like to display as a dashboard; however, I would really like a drop down button that can essentially pick out the data to plot.

I have data from several years: 2016, 2017, 2018, etc. I would like a drop down button, where the user can select 2018, for example, to view a column plot of the 2018 data. Then if they was to see 2017, the simply select it from the drop down button to plot 2017 data instead.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing something like this?

--- Additional information ---

Here is an example of my data.

[image]

Creating a PivotChart for 2016, for example,
[image]

How can I go about making it so multiple years can be selected (i.e. a tab for 2017 beside the 2016 tab), each with the 4 quarters?

Comment: How about a pivot chart?

Comment: Thanks PeterT, I have played around with this. Please see my edited question showing my process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rearrange your data a bit, you can achieve your chart with a slicer. So add an extra column and make your data look like this:

[image]

Then create your pivot chart and set up the fields to look like this:

[image]

And you'll get your pivot chart:

[image]

Now, keeping the chart selected, go to the *Analyze* ribbon, *Filter* group, and click *Insert Slicer*. Then choose *Year*. Your slicer sets up next to your chart and you can choose any or all years as needed.

[image]